# Detect clicks inside of iframe

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to detect how many times the user is clicking inside of an iframe. Its preferable to only count the click if the user is clicking a link inside of the iframe.

For example the user is navigating the website inside the iframe, everytime the user clicks on a link or button that takes them to a new page on the website, it will count a click.

So far I have only seen answers that register 1 click on focus like this
https://gist.github.com/jaydson/1780598

```
var myConfObj = {
  iframeMouseOver : false
}
window.addEventListener('blur',function(){
  if(myConfObj.iframeMouseOver){
    console.log('Wow! Iframe Click!');
  }
});

document.getElementById('webFrame').addEventListener('mouseover',function(){
   myConfObj.iframeMouseOver = true;
});
document.getElementById('webFrame').addEventListener('mouseout',function(){
    myConfObj.iframeMouseOver = false;
});
```

Using this method it does detect the click but it only detects the click when clicking inside the iframe for the first time and you have to click outside the iframe and back in which wont work for what I am trying to build. The reason being is the user would be expected to be browsing inside the iframe they wont be clicking in and out of the iframe.

Also the websites displayed in the iframe will not be from the same domain.

Expectation: Every click inside the iframe will increase `var clicks` by `1`
Actual Result: User click is registered once upon focus of iframe

Preferred Result: When user clicks a link inside the iframe that takes the user to a new page `var clicks` will be increased by `1`

Comment: Do you realize that the document inside an iframe is a complete document of its own? With its own execution context, scope and so on? What you try to do is simply not possible as far as I know. Take a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy

Comment: As @Flyer53 said, if this would be possible it would be a huge security risk. You have to find another way for tracking your users.

Comment: @cloned If you can already track when the user clicks inside of the iframe then it should be possible to track all clicks inside the iframe they dont have to track exactly what is being clicked just that it was clicked

Comment: Flyer explained why this isn't possible. So no, it's not possible.